# How to set multiple values in Firebase Database using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

```
@IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {
    ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(titleText.text)
}
```

What if I wanted to add subsections to post instead of just the title. Like *date*, *authors*, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a regular *[Swift dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)*, set the desired properties, and then call `setValue` using the same syntax as above.

For instance:

```
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = ...
let post = [
    "title":  "Incompleteness Theorem", 
    "author": "Kurt Gödel",
    "date":   "1931"
]
ref.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
```